# How to fix phpMyAdmin doesnt update but console data return sucessfully updated?

Tags: php, ajax, vue.js, axios

I need to implement update function in this project. It is a table with 1 button such as "Approve". For more information, below is the user interface.

[image: UI]

If the user pressed the "Approve" on certain row, then it will update the status to Approve. But then, for now, when i test it up by clicking the approve. It will not update anything including in phpMyAdmin. But console out the response which the image below:

[image: Console]

As you can see, the image above is now showing Update successfully.

The code below is for VueJs

```
approve(id){
        console.log(id);

        this.axios.post('ajaxupdate.php',{
            action:'update',
            id: id,
            approve: this.Approved
        }).then((response) => {

            this.loadAll();
            console.log(response);
        })
      }
```

Then this is the php ajax

```
    <?php
include "config.php";

$received_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$data = array();

if($received_data->action == 'update'){
 $data = array(
  $id   => $received_data->id,
 );

 $sql = "UPDATE warranty SET warranty_status='Approve' WHERE id=" .$id;
 
 $statement = $connect->prepare($sql);

 $statement->execute($data);

 $output = array(
  'message' => 'Data Updated'
 );

 echo json_encode($output);
}
 
?>
```

Comment: You create a query, but you don't actually execute it.

Comment: Then you output a success message - even when you _do_ execute the query, you'll need to check whether it executed (look at the return from the function) to know what to output. You also need to use prepared statements rather than concatenating strings into the query, and you've got an extra full-stop before your `$approve` variable in the above.

Comment: Noted, After i modify the code based on your explaination, It return another eror which is xhr.js:177 POST http://www.example.com/ajaxupdate.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Where is your `$id` variable coming from? Why do you create an array called `$data`? I can see you've started using prepared statements, but you still concatenate the `$id` variable (which doesn't exist) and don't actually use any parameters in it. Maybe you should get that code working in isolation before you start calling it from Ajax. You still don't check if the query executed without error before giving your "Updated" message.